# Redirect Multiple Domains to external URLs in Traefik

Tags: traefik

After reading the github issues related to this with a bunch of loose snippets, It's still completely unclear how to write simple 301 redirects in Traefik as I used to do in nginx like this:

```
server_name foo.com
return 301 https://bar.com
```

The plan is: redirect any request in http-scheme to https (same domain), regardless whether the domain exists or not like in nginx default host on port 80 with `redirect 301 https://$host`.
Then, matching the https-Host, return a redirect code with the new `Location:` - Header.

My base traefik.toml is:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      minVersion = "VersionTLS12"

[acme]
  email = "acme@mydomain.com"
  storage = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
  entryPoint = "https"
  onHostRule = true

[acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"

[file]
  directory = "/etc/traefik/conf/"
  watch = true
```

Now, how does a file in `conf/` must look like to adopt the above nginx redirect? It's about ~300 domains which are hosted at another place, so no backend needed, and it must not be 302/rewrites to be SEO-conform.

This pr https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/2570 seems to be near to what I want, but there's no documentation how to use it.

Comment: additional info: every domain has a specific counterpart, mostly just another TLD endings.

Comment: and I'm not sure about the onHostRule and what it actually does mean

Comment: did you find an answer to this problem? i'm in the same situation, need to enter 100s of 301 rules, and not sure of best method

Comment: no, still no solution, hence I'm still stuck with nginx and certbot, too.